# Provide Administrator credentials within script

Tags: scripting, windows-command-prompt, pstools, autoit

I am writing a script that runs from a user account.  The script needs to execute another script as the Administrator account.

- Tried AutoIt's [`RunAs`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/RunAs.htm) - didn't work.
- Tried [`PsExec`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) - the same.
- Tried CMD's [`RunAs`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771525.aspx) - needs manual typing of password.

What are my other options?

Comment: Could you provide examples of the syntax you used with each option? Which version of Windows are you using? How is UAC configured?

Answer (score 0):

I use Runasspc by Robotronic.de. 
With it it you can create an encrypted script file and run it in command line.

Unfortunately the official site (http://www.robotronic.de/runasspcEn.html) is not working properly at the time, so you cannot download it from there. 
However I found the runasspcen.zip (contains the executables and instructions) from here:
http://www.leblogosd.fr/wordpress/runas-en-ligne-commande/

Comment: The Robotronic.de had similar application called RunasRob. I haven't studied it, but it may suit your purposes: http://www.robotronic.de/runasroben.html

Comment: Now the download from http://www.robotronic.de/runasspcEn.html seems to be working OK.

Answer (score 0):

Try running psexec with the -i option. That will run the command as the System user which basically gives it god mode.

You can write some impersonate code that will accomplish the same thing. There is a SystemElevate.au3 on the autoit forums that has been put together.